# How to get images path from golang project file

Tags: go

I am a beginner in making a REST full API using golang, what I want to ask is to get an image file from the path in my golang project, before I have successfully uploaded the image and saved it in the path and the path I have saved it in mysql database, how do I do it to be able to display the image in the form of a link, so I can load it on android,

and how to make it like this
"http: // localhost: 3004 / images / imagename.jpg" 
inside the json result ( ImgEvent )??

please help me... thanks

```golang
func (idb *InDB) GetEvents(c *gin.Context) {
    var (
        events    []structs.Event
        newEvents structs.Event
        result    gin.H
    )

    getimage := "img_event"
    data := idb.DB.Select(getimage).Find(&events)
    if data != nil {
        result = gin.H{
            "message": "Not found",
        }
    }
    newEvents.ImgEvent = getimage

    data = idb.DB.Find(&events)

    if len(events) <= 0 {
        result = gin.H{
            "result": nil,
            "count":  0,
        }
    } else {
        result = gin.H{
            "data": events,
        }
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
}

========= Respone Json ===========

{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "CreatedAt": "2019-07-28T22:38:20Z",
            "UpdatedAt": "2019-08-12T09:51:41Z",
            "DeletedAt": null,
            "Judul": "test1",
            "Isi": "Dalam menyambut ulang tahun Accent-er Regional JawaBarat yang ke 3.\r\n\r\nKami mengundang seluruh member terdaftar maupun non member untuk ikut hadir meramaikan acara ini.\r\n\r\nYang akan di selenggarakan di\r\n\r\nCikole,Lembang Bandung
            "ImgEvent": "event-images/event-bukalapak.jpg",
            "TotalComments": 1,
            "TotalLikes": 5,
            "TotalView": 3
        },
```

Comment: Please ask programming questions, not how to implement things. Try breaking this question/problem into the smallest part possible—i.e. where does this fail for you?

Comment: Ok thanks for your correction im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should a create a file server to be able create an http link for files. You can use net/http's [Fileserver](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?s=20537:20577#L703) for the same. Fileserver is a good choice if you want it for a small time, like as long as you API server is running. 
Another choice would be to create an FTP server and use that to store images.

Comment: Thanks dor quick answer, before i already make this fileserver to handle http request but response not what i want.. maybe ill try again

Comment: What response did you expect and what did you get, please mention that, and also, how did you use Fileserver.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, i expected was responsr at field image can display in android when i get image item..in android im using glide for populate images